# Memory Leak VBA - Arrays with Dictionaries of Dictionaries

Tags: excel, vba, memory, dictionary

I'm running out of memory (I have 16GB) in a script I am running. Here is a little background:

I am generating an array that is ~150k rows by 8 column as the basis for my calculations.

Then, for each "row" of values (nothing is ever written to the worksheet), I am making a LOT of calculations, which I am storing in various data structures (I have 3 main structures at this point). One of these structures is composed of the following:

A Variant Array with 150k Dictionaries. Each Dictionary has ~4 Key-Item pairs. Each item in each dictionary is another dictionary, containing exactly 9 key-item pairs. All keys are Strings and all items are Doubles.

Essentially, this is the same thing as:

```
Dim Array(1 to 150000, 1 to 4, 1 to 9) as Double
```

Except I want to be able to reference the values with text strings -- hence the dictionaries.

An example would be

```
Value = Array(2401)("Key1")("Key2")
```

I wouldn't think this would be too much for VBA to handle -- we're talking 150,000 * 4 * 9 individual doubles = 5.4M doubles for each of the 3 main data structures. I don't have that much experience with programming and memory management, but sure that wouldn't consume 16GB of memory!

As such, I'm thinking there's a problem in how I'm generating these data structures that is causing a memory leak somewhere.

Essentially the loop looks like this

```
Dim TempDict1 as Dictionary
Dim TempDict2 as Dictionary
Dim FinalArray() as Variant
ReDim FinalArray(1 to 150000) as Variant
Dim Calculations as Double

For i = 1 to 150000
    Set TempDict = NewDictionary
    for j = 1 to 5
        Set TempDict2 = NewDictionary
        for k = 1 to 9
            Calculations = 2*2
            TempDict2.Add Key:= KeyK, Item:= Calculations
        Next k
        TempDict.Add Key:= KeyJ, Item:= TempDict2
        ' TempDict2.RemoveAll (This causes an error)
    next j
    Set FinalArray(i) = TempDict
    ' TempDict.RemoveAll (This causes an error)
Next i
```

What am I doing wrong here? I've tried destroying the temporary dictionaries after adding them to the parent item, but that actually gives me a type error.

UPDATE: I've tried setting the temporary dictionaries to nothing instead of removing all. This doesn't cause any errors, but it still consumes a lot of memory. With 37k iterations, it consumes 8.4GB of memory.

Comment: Have you tried setting `Set TempDict2 = Nothing` after adding it to `TempDict` and then `Set TempDict = Nothing` after adding it to array? Have you tried smaller iteration say `For i = 1 To 1000`? Did it work? Up to what level does it fail?

Comment: I haven't tried setting it to nothing. However, when I destroy it, it seems to destroy the data that was added to the array. Is it passed by ref rather than by val? It works in an iteration up to 40k rows, consuming about 9GB of memory. FYI there are 3 of these array structures.

Comment: Each dictionary consists of string key, double value, and a hash table to find items quick, so in fact you have 16M strings, 16M doubles, 450k small hash tables and 3 big hash tables. I can't estimate memory size of those structures, but designing some more efficient way of storing data might be necessary in this case.

Comment: Understood. Just so long as the memory usage is actually coming from actual data storage, and not some sort of leak.

Comment: I tried it and it freeze at 50000. So yeah, maybe that is the limitation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is some sort of bug or memory leak, but the fact is that this is an extremely memory-inefficient way to store data.

As such, I've edited the code to use 3 dimensional arrays with separate dictionaries to associate the indices of arrays with text strings, which is working great.

I was able to store 8 different 3D arrays (150k by 8 by 13) and 7 different 2D arrays (150k 13), both of doubles. Overhead doesn't seem to be too high. Given a size of 8 bytes per double, theoretical memory usage is 1.11GB, which isn't too bad.